# Chatbase return 200, but overview is empty

Tags: chatbase

When I send data to Chatbase, I receive a message_id and status 200, but nothing appears in the overview. Even after 6 hours. Is this a common problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It can typically take up to an hour to begin seeing your messages on the Overview reports. However, depending on your timezone and the date range you select, it could be delayed further. If you are still experiencing the issue, you can contact chatbase-support@google.com with the api key of your bot and I will be happy to look at your bot messages to assure that everything is in order.